# Warning: “The method parameter $context is never used”

Tags: magento2, php

I am getting issue "The method parameter $context is never used" in my InstallData.php script when submitting Magento2 extension to marketplace in technical review.

Can Anyone help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, you can use following

```
// @codingStandardsIgnoreStart     
public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)     
// @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
```